# I'm getting Segmentation fault (core dumped) while using getline

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

Here's my code:

```
char* ReadOneLine(char *FileName)
{
  FILE *FilePointer = fopen(FileName, "r");
  assert(FilePointer != NULL);
  char* new_line = NULL;
  size_t *line_lenght = 0;
  //ssize_t line_size;
  getline(&new_line, line_lenght, FilePointer);
  assert(new_line == NULL);
  return(new_line);
}


int main()
{
  char* buffer = ReadOneLine("example"); //Buffer will do somthing later...
  return (0);
}
```

I keep getting this error while trying to run the program and I can't understand why.
Plus I know I'm supposed to free new_line after using it but I'm not sure where because I'm sending new_line to other functions as well.

Comment: Add code to `free` the line after the program is finished using it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pointer `line_lenght` doesn't point anywhere.  It contains a NULL pointer.  So when `getline` tried to dereference this null pointer you invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) which in this case results in a crash.

Instead of defining `line_lenght` as a `size_t *`, define it as `size_t` and pass its address.

```
size_t line_length = 0;
getline(&new_line, &line_length, FilePointer);
```

As for where to call `free`, since `ReadOneLine` returned the malloced buffer then the function that called `ReadOneLine` needs to call `free`.  In this case, than means you need to call `free(buffer)` in the `main` function when you're done with it.

Comment: and maybe fix the spelling, too :-)